# Select href with id and class using xpath

Tags: xpath

let say I have DOM like this:

```
<div id="tabsmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="one"><a href="'#foo" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="tab1"></a>foo</li>
        <li class="two"><a href="#baz" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="tab2">baz</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I would like to get the text from `<a href>` elements:

```
# desired output: ['#foo', '#baz']
```

How to do it using `xpath` and using combination `id` and element with a specific `class` within `id` ?

Already tried:

```
 some_doc.xpath('//a[@id="tabsmenu"]/[@class="ui-tabs-anchor"]/@href')

 # select all href tags of any a element that is in id tabsmenu and class attribute ui-   tabs-anchor
```

EDIT - corrected `tabmenu` into `tabsmenu`

Comment: I guess foo should actually be inside the `a` tag, right? Also the id is not `tabsmenu` but rather `tabmenu` and also `ui-   tabs-anchor` should be `ui-tab-anchor`. Also, the text of the `href` elements is not `foo` and `baz` but rahter `'#foo` and `#baz`. There are many errors in your question...

Comment: thanks for feedback - it is updated.Yes, `foo` is inside `a tag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely looking for something like this:

```
//div[@id='tabsmenu']//a[@class='ui-tabs-anchor']/@href
```

That will get all `href` attributes that are part of an `a` tag with the class `ui-tabs-anchor` and inside a `div` element with the id `tabsmenu`.

Also you might want to take a look at this question:

[Find out if class name contains certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247327/find-out-if-class-name-contains-certain-text/20247406#20247406)

This is because the class will match the exact value (`ui-tabs-anchor`) and maybe some additional class might be added there such as `class="ui-tabs-anchor disabled"` and then there will not be a match in there.

Comment: hm I am getting this when checking this solution: `:exeption is:  Invalid expression: ////xmlns:div[@id = "tabsmenu"]//xmlns:a[@class = "ui-tabs-anchor"]/xmlns:`

Comment: The xpath is fine, I've tested it on [videlibri](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi). That must be some issue with the programming language. Is that just an HTML page?