# XPath Select by text within link, link also contains i

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to use XPath to find a link in a list of links (tabs) based on the text of the link. The problem is that they also have icons (which are at the moment hidden) so simply using text() isn't matching them.

I tried:

- `//ul[contains(@class, 'nav-tabs')]/li/a[text()='Details']`
- `//ul[contains(@class, 'nav-tabs')]/li/a[normalize-space(text())='Details']`

but neither finds the Details tab. Simply doing `//ul[contains(@class, 'nav-tabs')]/li/a` does get me all the links and I can see the `<i>` and `Details` text within them then, but I can't get just the "Details" link.

I wanted to avoid using contains() because I am concerned that we will have two tabs that could be matched that way if one word is within a larger word, so I wanted to match it exactly.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#s52ae1defa2b1e_1" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="icon-exclamation-sign has-errors hide"></i>
            Details
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#s52ae1defa2b1e_2" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="icon-exclamation-sign has-errors hide"></i>
            Description
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#s52ae1defa2b1e_3" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="icon-exclamation-sign has-errors hide"></i>
            SEO
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your first trial works perfectly for me

Comment: When I do it in the console, it doesn't work, and it doesn't work when running the tests in Behat either, so I'm not sure how it worked for you.

Comment: I just copy-pasted the HTML file and the XPath expression [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) and it displayed the `Details` anchor. Also I would recommend you to take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247327/find-out-if-class-name-contains-certain-text/20247406#20247406) to see why the `contains` as you're using might give you trouble in the future by matching unwanted classes such as `disabled-nav-tabs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `//ul[contains(@class, 'nav-tabs')]/li/a[normalize-space(.)='Details']`

or `//ul[contains(@class, 'nav-tabs')]/li/a[text()[normalize-space(.)='Details']]`

[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) expects a string as argument, so the context node `.` will be converted to a string. In this case, the text representation inside the `a` element.

You can even ommit the context node and use `//ul[contains(@class, 'nav-tabs')]/li/a[normalize-space()='Details']`

From [the XPath 1.0 docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space):

> The normalize-space function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space. Whitespace characters are the same as those allowed by the S production in XML. If the argument is omitted, it defaults to the context node converted to a string, in other words the string-value of the context node.

---

Some more explanation after OP's comment:

`text()` is a node test (see [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests)) but does not give you the string value of a context node, it's a test in your XPath expression

> The node test text() is true for any text node.

`normalize-space(text())` would return a string indeed, **but an empty one in your case**. The node-set argument, `text()`, that'll match all text child nodes of the context node, will be converted to a string value, but only considering the first node in the node-set. See [the `string()` function description](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string):

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of **the node** in the node-set **that is first in document order**. If the node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

This also applies to `normalize-space()`.

So if you use `normalize-space(text())`, you'll get an empty string in your `a` context.

You can verify this with `//ul[contains(@class, 'nav-tabs')]/li/a/text()` on http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html with your sample HTML. You'll get

```
Text=''   <-- this will be used in //li/a[normalize-space(text())...
Text='Details'
Text=''
Text='Description'
Text=''
Text='SEO'
```

And you can see that `normalize-space(//ul[contains(@class, 'nav-tabs')]/li/a/text())` returns an empty string.

But if you use `normalize-space(.)` or `normalize-space()`, **the string value** that will be stripped from leading and trailing whitespace **will be the string-value of the context node, `a` in your case**:

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.

Comment: Doesn't text() return a string? I could have sworn we used normalize-space(text()) before and it worked

Comment: @Jessica, I've added some further explanation. Hope it helps.